# Trouble with what precedes and follows the ID-pattern

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access-2007, delimiter

I have a VBA RegEx function that searches for a ID with a pattern of 1 letter followed by 6 digits.  I've been using the pattern `[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{6}` to find the IDs but am absolutely stuck on special cases.

Typically, the IDs are surrounded by non-character/numbers like *"domain\J123456, Last login [etc]"* so I tried `[^a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{6}[^a-zA-Z\d]{1}` which kinda-worked.  Where this pattern-string fails is

- When the ID is at the beginning of the string: *"J123456, Last login [etc]"*
- When the ID is at the end of the string: *"domain\J123456"*
- When the ID is the whole string: *"J123456"*

A further frustration is that VBA's implementation of RegEx is less than compliant and sometimes uses non-standard expressions.  I know I could do multiple RegEx searches but that seems inefficient. Any help from The Gods would be greatly appreciated.

**Specs:**
I'm using MS Access 2007 and the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library (and my environment is locked down so I can't introduce new/different libraries into the mix).

***EDIT***:
Here is some mocked up entries that present some of the scenarios.  I'll **bold** what should be a match.  There will only ever be 1 valid match per entry.

- Sid="S-21-121X4440339-682Z003330" Name="Smith, John" LoginName="NAEAST\**J123456**"
- **J123456** Key=B214440339-1979792683-682E003330
- L398938943-090934989 By **J123456**
- **J123456**

***EDIT - The Solution***

Based on the accepted answer below, here is the working function for anyone who needs it.

```
Public Function findID(search_str As String)
  '  Find [letter][6-digit number] ID in string
  Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
  Dim matches

  findSID = ""
  regEx.Pattern = "(?:^|[^a-zA-Z\d])([a-zA-Z]{1}\d{6})(?![a-zA-Z\d])"
  regEx.Global = True
  If regEx.test(search_str) Then
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(search_str)
    '-- Some of the matches return the match and left-most border-char.  Trim it off
    findID = Right(matches(0).Value, 7)  
   Else
    findID = "No match"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have specified.  I'm trying to extract it.

Comment: Then perhaps I misunderstood.  The RegEx pattern in the accepted answer will tell you whether the source string contains a match.  But it does not return the matching substring.  Am I off base here?

Comment: @HansUp, You are correct.  The returned substring isn't the match sought.  I also encountered another false match, cited in the first answer below.

Comment: You may want to edit `findSID = ""` (or remove it as both If branches assign to `findID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a regex of the form

```
(?:^|[^a-zA-Z\d])([a-zA-Z]{1}\d{6})(?![a-zA-Z\d])
```

- The capture group 1 will contain the ID
- `(?![a-zA-Z\d])` asserts that the regex is not followed by digits or alphabets

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/wV3mP9/7)

Comment: Sorry about the accept/un-accept.  The 2nd [^a-zA-Z\d]? is allowing a match when searching a string like "sdfasdf\r0189060sdkjlksjd".  Where "r018906" would be allowed if it ended with a non-letter/number, the extra 0 should disqualify it from a match

Comment: Correct.  The logs I'm searching can have lots of hashed "junk" per entry that contain "[1 letter][6 digits]" sequences, but the IDs I'm looking for are either by themselves, at the beginning/ending of an entry or delimited by non-letter/number characters

Comment: @JimM I have completly changed the regex. To match the new examples you provided. Take a look. Hope it helps you

Comment: The mystery deepens.  It didn't seem to work for the 2nd entry (ID is in the very front) so I added a ? behind your first token and it works.  The full regex now looks like: [^a-zA-Z\d]?([a-zA-Z]{1}\d{6})(?![a-zA-Z\d])  The only downside seems to be the inclusion of the leftmost character if it passes the regex match but I can cope with that.

Comment: ok - Every time I put in @nu11p01n73r, SO strips it out.  Can you edit your response to include the question mark after the first token? See my above comment for exact placement. And even though the post-rules frown on it, thanks a ton!!

Comment: @JimM But i dont think you may get the correct output then, becuase the optional part will then match strings which are not intended see https://regex101.com/r/wV3mP9/6

Comment: Change the first `[^a-zA-Z\d]` to `(?:^|[^a-zA-Z\d])` to match tokens at the beginning of the entry.

Comment: @AlanMoore I really missed that. Corrected in answer